How to Handle Database-Agnostic Queries for Relationships in Spring Data JPA?
I’m working on a Spring Boot application where I need to fetch groups associated with a user based on their ID. Currently, I’m using the following approach in my repository:
@Query("SELECT g FROM Group g JOIN g.members m WHERE m.id = :memberId")  
List<Group> findGroupsByMemberId(@Param("memberId") Long memberId); 

While this works fine with SQL databases, I’m concerned about its compatibility with NoSQL databases or other database systems in the future. If I ever migrate the application to a NoSQL DB (e.g., MongoDB), this JPQL query would no longer work.

Don't. There is no query language that spans all types of datastores. If you ever switch modifying your queries is probably the least of your worries.

The odds of you switching from one relational database to another are pretty low, and writing all your SQL to be ANSI is next to impossible. But trying to remain compatible with a NoSQL database seems a highly unlikely usecase, they solve such different problems that you should be using the correct database type from the start.

NoSQL are flat objects. If you needed to conform to ever use a NoSQL DB, you should build your app using those requirements upfront, test it on NoSQL; that app will be pretty easy to have run on a relational database which has much more support. Everything is a trade off.
